# useOriginalMessage() and multiple 'from' nodes

Tags: grails, groovy, apache-camel

I'm using the Grails routing plugin which allows defining Camel routes with a Groovy DSL syntax very similar to the Java DLS syntax.

Suppose I have the following RouteBuilder:

```
class MyRoute extends RouteBuilder {
  from('activemq:route1')
    .to('someProcessor1')
    .to('direct:route2')

  from('direct:route2')
    .to('someProcessor2')

  onException(Throwable.class).useOriginalMessage().handled(true)
    .to('activemq:route.failed')
}
```

If I have a message that starts at `activemq:route1`, then moves through `direct:route2` but fails in the `someProcessor2`, then I end up with the message as it started at `activemq:route1` in my `activemq:route.failed` queue... but that's not what I want. If I have a failure in `someProcessor2`, I want the message as it started at `direct:route2` (and likewise, if I have a failure in `someProcessor1`, I want the `activemq:route1` message in my failed queue).

Is there any Apache Camel feature that allows me to "reset" the original message at the beginning of a RouteDefintion (i.e. `from(<uri>)`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use something besides `direct:` to join your routes (seda, vm, activemq) and it will behave as you suggested...otherwise, you can also explicitly preserve the relevant state of the message in a header and restore it in the onException clause, etc.

Comment: Interesting, is there anything comparable to `direct` that has the behavior I desire (simple synchronous message)? All of the alternatives you listed are asynchronous and would change the semantics of my routes. I am currently going down the explicit save / restore approach you described, but wanted to make sure I don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: 'direct' reuses the same thread/Exchange across routes...its great in some ways, but this is one case that I've had to workaround in the past...if you find a better approach, let me know